# How to decrease passphrase length for snmp?

Tags: snmp, passphrase

We got this error when running this command :

```
[cacti ~]$ snmpwalk -v 3 -a MD5 -u super -x AES -X AAAAAA 10.X.X.X
2011-01-20 16:58:12 Error: passphrase chosen is below the length requirements of the USM  (min=8).
2011-01-20 16:58:12 snmpwalk:  (The supplied password length is too short.)
Error generating a key (Ku) from the supplied privacy pass phrase.
```

Do you have any idea how to decrease the USM's length parameter? We can't change the password that is under 8 characters..

Answer (score 2):

You are fighting the IETF RFC if you insist using a short passphrase,

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3414

> If the Appendix A algorithm is used, SNMP implementations (and SNMP
> configuration applications) must ensure that passwords are at least 8
> characters in length.

This is a standard, so your only choice is to use a long enough passphrase.

For AES, the recommended passphrase length is 12,

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3826.txt

> The following are recommended in regard to user passwords:
>
> - Password length SHOULD be at least 12 octets.
> - Password sharing SHOULD be prohibited so that passwords are not
>   shared among multiple SNMP users.
> - Implementations SHOULD support the use of randomly generated
>   passwords as a stronger form of security.